# How could be a WCF REST feasible to accept both XML and JSON as Request?

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, service, wcf-rest

I have created WCF REST service which accepts RequestFormat as **JSON** and **BodyStyle = Wrapped** . I want to make my service to accept XML if the consumer (***.NET , JAVA , PHP , JAVASCRIPT e.t.c.,***) POSTS the ***complex*** ( class object ) data. I have enabled the attribute (automaticFormatSelectionEnabled) to true in web.config . I have few questions as below

1. Can we make a REST service to accept XML or JSON/both formats as Request ?
2. Does BodyStyle vary in accepting both formats ?
3. How could we send the complex object to a POST contract for JSON or XML / both formats ?
4. What are the precautions to be taken while creating REST service that can be consumed by all Platforms ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your controller actions would have the same signature you could make the JSON be a `GET` and the XML be a `POST`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string xml)
{
  ...
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test(string json)
{
  ...
}
```

As for the POST you'd probably have to have a dedicated Action for POSTing XML or JSON

Comment: Does the input parameter of the POST method is string ? Either Compound data type or Built in data type ..